# Objective C - What causes copying of data to float array to result in continuous memory increase?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

When I call this method

```
- (int)runDetection:(NSArray *)data length:(int)length
{
    long count = [data count];

    float *dataArray = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float *) * count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        dataArray[i] = [[data objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
    }

    free(dataArray);

    return -2;
}
```

But after commenting this piece of code, the app works fine. No continuous memory increase.

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    dataArray[i] = [[data objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
}
```

The memory is freed after use so why is this causing memory increase?

Comment: It doesn't cause memory leak.

Comment: It should be `sizeof(float)` in your code, this won't cause a memory leak just make `dataArray` potentially twice the size it needs to be (a `float *` might be 8 bytes, a `float` 4). Other than that like @trungduc I can see no immediate memory leak in this loop as shown.

Comment: You need to post the code to snowboy->RunDetection as that could be your culprit. You are freeing the memory, so it would seem RunDetection is perhaps doing something with memory. BTW, not sure if this is all pre-existing code, but if you don't want to mess with memory management, you could use C++ (ie. std::vector)

Comment: @MobileBen Hi, it's imposible that snowboy->runDetection would cause the problem. Because the code alone without executing the snowboy->runDetection would also cause the continuous increase in memory.

Comment: @CRD Hi. I revised my title of the question. It keeps on increasing the memory. The method is called every after a chunk of data is read from audio recorder of phone. The data comes in very fast, so this method is called multiple times in a second.

Comment: What kind of objects are in the array `data`, and what does that class's `floatValue` method do?

Comment: @finalstatic your description states "After commenting out the piece of code above. The app works fine." which lead me to believe when the code exists (`RunDetection`) the problem exists. If this isn't case you may want to re-phrase your description.

Comment: @Caleb The array contains numbers. The floatValue is used to get the float value of each number.

Comment: @finalstatic sorry if I'm being slow but I do not think your edits have helped. It further confuses things. "after commenting this piece of code" has no reference/context to anything. If you mean to say you "commented out"`snowboy->RunDetection()` you should be explicit about this. Clarity is your friend when you're asking for help. My point in mentioning this previously is your response was counter what your description was saying.

Comment: One thing I just noticed is you do have an error in your code. `(float *)malloc(sizeof(float *) * count)` should really be `(float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * count)` On a 64-bit processor, the size of `float *` will be 8 bytes. You're allocating `count` pointers to `float`. This you're really just allocating a larger space (on a 64-bit processor).

Comment: finalstatic - The incorrect `sizeof` isn't your problem *per se*, I was just pointing it out as @MobileBen has now also done. As nothing else is helping try changing your declaration to `float dataArray[count];` and also remove the `free()`. This changes your code to use a stack allocated array, potentially not good if `count` is large, and removes the issue being connected to `malloc`/`free` in anyway. If that doesn't remove the leak it is definitely elsewhere.

Comment: @CRD Hey, sorry ... I didn't read all the comments carefully and I just saw you already cited the `sizeof(float)` issue early on. My bad.

Comment: @MobileBen - No worries!